# How to conver variant structure in R

Tags: r, rcpp

Our project has dll, which has function which returns 2d array flattened to 1d array of Microsoft variant structure.
It looks like (assume VT type is int)
1 2 3
4 5 6
and it returns 1 2 3 4 5 6 (array)
number of rows and columns in array keep on changing (2x3 or 4x5 or 1000x1)
I am able to call function from .cpp using rcpp. I need way to convert the variant array into R data type(s)
One way is convert it into list. But to convert them in row column format I need to process them again which I want to avoid.
I cannot see any package in R which can help me here.Any suggestion ? Can we create nested lists dynamically in rcpp ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, but please don't cross-post.  You just sent this to the mailing list an hour or so ago.

Comment: Yes I did. I thought it will help to get solution quick. If someone not suing mailing list but aware of it will answer this.